# Does Umbraco 7.7 support concurrent users?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

Say, we have multiple users editing same document in parallel.
Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

For example, disabling the document from being editing if there's already another editor changes content.

Comment: It used to be a feature of a Pro package called Concierge however with the recent addition of Signalr as a dependency for Umbraco it should be relatively straightforward to notify users but I don't know if someone has yet created a package to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There used to be a few packages that helped deal with this issue.  So far none of them have been ported and released as supporting v7.

The only one I could find that may be close is this one:

[Look who's editing now](https://github.com/TimGeyssens/LookWhosEditingToo)

It's a work in progress version, but perhaps its close enough you could use it or even help get it working.